# как запустить приложение на android в kivy launcher, имея исходники github?

Tags: python, android, github, kivy

Хочу запустить вот это https://github.com/Android-for-Python/c4k_opencv_example/tree/main на своем телефоне. Нужно ли для этого билдить apk, если да, то как это делается? Вообще хотелось бы в идеале запустить это через kivy launcher (без создания apk). Пробовала втупую (понимаю, что это что-то совсем не то): копировала папку проекта на телефон, добавляла в папку проекта файл android.txt с таким содержанием:

```
    title=My
    author=me
    orientation=portrait
```

kivy launcher проект видит, начинает запускать и сразу же вылетает.

Answer (score 0):

Собрать проект надо.

1. В самом проекте есть инструкция [Install Camera4Kivy on Android](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/camera4kivy#buildozerspec)
2. Инструкция по использованию Buildozer [Create a package for Android](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html)

Так же можете попробовать использовать [PyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=ru&gl=US)